# Why does PyCharm tell me the pyodbc module cannot be found when it works?

Tags: python, pycharm, pyodbc

I downloaded and installed the latest Python (3.7), and installed pyodbc both through the standard "pip install pyodbc" method and downloading and installing the unofficial wrapper. But still, in my script that uses pyodbc, PyCharm underlines pyodbc in red, and when I hover my mouse over it, it tells me "module not found". On my Settings | Project Interpreter screen, it shows that pyodbc is installed, and when I run my script, it works.

My problem is that it doesn't show me function arguments when I type a function name and the open parenthesis, as it does for modules that it knows about. I would like to get rid of the error marker and get the benefits of PyCharm's full support for pyodbc. How do I do that?

Note:  This is very close to a duplicate of a question I posted over a year and a half ago, but I did not get an answer that helped at that time.  One commenter on that thread suggested I uninstall pyodbc and then run python -m install pyodbc.  I did that, and got no change.

Comment: You can "invalidate cache and restart" Pycharm. When you install a new third-party package, Pycharm does not automatically re-index your project with its dependencies.

Comment: Is your PyCharm project configured to use the same environment/interpreter as the one you've installed the package for?

Comment: @schwobaseggl This is strange: mine always updates the cache itself in an online fashion (when I install something in an appropriate environment, PyCharm detects the new package in several seconds). And I've been using PyCharm for many years.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Interesting, we have been using the professional version for years, too, and have always had the issue that we had to restart the IDE when we pip installed a new package. One workaround is to edit the current interpreter (and then not edit it at all) when the save triggers indexing.

Comment: @schwobaseggl re: *"When you install a new third-party package, Pycharm does not automatically re-index your project with its dependencies."* - It always does for me, at least when I install the package via Settings > Project Interpreter ....

Comment: Invalidating the cache and restarting PyCharm did not help.  I tried to install the package via Settings > Project Interpreter, but I could not do it.  Uninstalling from the intepreter page did not work, claiming that a main function could not be found, and once I uninstalled it, I could not find a way to install it from there.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Well, seems like you've been having some local problems, because both I and @GordThormpson haven't experienced the same behaviour. It's enough to install a package via `pip` or `conda` and wait for a couple of seconds for PyCharm to pick it up. I'm using the professional version, too.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON are you using any form of a virtual environment? Have you checked whether your PyCharm project is configured to use the same interpreter? Have you used `sudo` to install the package in the first place?

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON - When you open Settings > Project Interpreter what version of pip does it report as being currently installed?

Comment: I am not using a virtual environment.  My PyCharm is configured to run the version of Python I used to install pyodbc (3.7).  I did not use sudo because I am not running under Unix.  I am running in Windows 7.  I used the version of pip included with version 3.7.  I am using pip version 10.0.1.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON then, I guess, you can't install or delete anything from PyCharm itself, because it doesn't have the rights to tinker with your system-wide installation (I don't know how Windows manages rights, but that's how Unix-like systems behave). Can you install Miniconda (https://conda.io/miniconda.html) for your system, create an environment and configure your project to use that environment? It's generally recommended to use virtual environments (either Python's built-in virtualenv or conda): it will help you avoid version conflicts in the long run.

Comment: @ROBERTRICHARDSON you can then simply install the package using `conda install` or `pip` from within the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The following answer was based on testing with PyCharm 2018.1. PyCharm 2018.2.1 includes an updated "packaging_tool.py" that plays nicely with pip 10+.

TL;DR: Update your PyCharm.

---

I was able to reproduce your issue with pip 18.0. When PyCharm installs a package from `File > Settings > Project Interpreter` it calls a helper script named "packaging_tool.py" which is incompatible with pip versions 10 and higher, so attempting to install *any* packages from there will result in

> AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'

JetBrains will have to fix that script to completely resolve the issue. (Their current workaround appears to be to pin pip at version 9.x. Even though Project Interpreter window lists pip 18.0 as "latest" it won't upgrade to it if we select pip and click the upgrade (up arrow) button.)

In the meantime, a workaround for pip_10+ is to

- open a Terminal window in PyCharm (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>),
- run `pip install pyodbc`,
- close the Terminal window and open `File > Settings > Project Interpreter`,
- try to install some other package, like pandas (the install will fail for the same reason),
- close the "Available Packages" dialog, then
- click the "OK" button to close the "Settings" dialog.

That should trigger PyCharm to re-scan the installed packages and enable pyodbc code completion in the PyCharm editor. (You may need to restart PyCharm for the change to take effect.)

Comment: Thank you.  I just heard from JetBrains tech support.  They said that problem was fixed long ago, and that I need to upgrade PyCharm.  I did, and it works.

Comment: I'm still getting this problem and I'm on 2019.1